# To see the results of patternsearch optimization for each iteration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a optimization problem which is very time consuming and I need to do it many times (This is somehow a trial and error problem for me). However, I do not want to wait for the final result. I need to see the result of optimization at each iteration. More specifically, I want to see the x value (the solution) and am not so interested in fval (objective function value at x). Unfortunately, patternsearch only shows fval and not the solution of optimization at each iteration. I know that I should fix this problem through the "Output Function" and spent a lot of time and could not understand how to do it. To make everything convenient for you and let's consider the following simple optimization problem:

```
options = optimoptions('patternsearch');
options = optimoptions(options,'Display', 'iter','TolX',1e-6);
x0=2;lb=-3;ub=3;
x = patternsearch(@(x)x^2,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

The first few lines we see on the command window looks like the following:

```
Iter     f-count          f(x)      MeshSize     Method
    0        1              4             1      
    1        2              4           0.5     Refine Mesh
    2        3              0             1     Successful Poll
```

Unfortunately, I see nothing about x.

Would you please change my code so that I can also see the solution (x) at each iteration, it is greatly appreciated!

Babak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid output function handler for `patternsearch` should be specified as follows:

```
function [stop,options,optchanged] = fun(optimvalues,options,flag)
```

The following code should be enough to show the information you are looking for:

```
options = optimoptions('patternsearch');
options = optimoptions(options,'Display','iter','OutputFcns',@custom,'TolX',1e-6);
x0 = 2; lb = -3; ub = 3;
x = patternsearch(@(x)x^2,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);

function [stop,options,optchanged] = custom(optimvalues,options,flag)
    stop = false;
    optchanged = false;

    if (strcmp(flag,'iter'))
        disp(['   Iteration performed for X=' num2str(optimvalues.x)]);
    end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
Iter     Func-count       f(x)      MeshSize     Method
  0           1            4             1      
  Iteration performed for X=2
  1           2            4           0.5       Refine Mesh
  Iteration performed for X=0
  2           3            0             1       Successful Poll
  Iteration performed for X=0
  3           3            0           0.5       Refine Mesh
  Iteration performed for X=0
  4           5            0          0.25       Refine Mesh
  Iteration performed for X=0
   ...
```

It's just an example and you can, of course, tweak the function so that the text is displayed the way you prefer.